# How do you read .txt with tab separated items that are on one line to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have this .txt:
'4  1   15  12'

It's just one long line separating its' items with tab. I need to read it into a list containing **int** items.

I can't seem to make pandas, csv module or open to do the trick.

This kinda works:

```
f = open('input.txt') 
for line in f:
    memory = line.split()
for item in memory:
    item = int(item)

print(memory)
```

> ['4', '1', '15', '12']

But it gives me an error when i compare its' max value to an int:

```
 max_val = max(memory)
 while max_val > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Your `memory` list contains strings, not integers.  The `item = int(item)` conversion does not affect the contents of the list.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem i need help with =)

Comment: Replace your second `for` loop with `memory = list(map(int, memory))`. That will create a new list with each element being an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though the text in the question was not `tab spaced`.
I have created a tab spaced file and the following works:

```py
import pandas as pd

test_file = "C:\\Users\\lefcoe\\Desktop\\test.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(test_file, delimiter='\t', header=None)

print(df)



#%% convert to a list of ints
my_list = df.loc[0, :].values.tolist()
my_list_int = [int(x) for x in my_list]
my_list_int

#%% get the max
m = max(my_list_int)
print(m)
```

result:

```
   1  1  2  3
0  4  1  15 12

15
```

Comment: Oh i like this to_list() thingy. Gonna try it later, thank you

Comment: this solution does not use `index[]` as it is empty. It simply converts `df.columns`to a list. It then converts the list of strings to integers. From this it finds the max...

Comment: @Daria,  yes,  it is very helpful when moving between dataFrames or numpy arrays and the standard python list...

Comment: it doesn't work with file containing "0 2 7 0": >>    memory = [int(x) for x in df_list]
>>ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.1'

Comment: why would it read 0 as 0.1?

Comment: `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 2, 7, 0.1]`

Comment: i have amended the code to work.  the reason that it did not work that way was because columns can not have the same name (so 0 becomes 0.1) whereas rows can contain the same values.

Answer (score 0):

its a TypeError you cant check if a type(str) is a type(int) because they are both different types

```
max_val = max(memory)
print(type(max_val))
>>> <class 'str'>
```

just change `max_val` to an `int` for example

```
max_val = max(memory)
while int(max_val) > 0:
```

Comment: This gives errors later. Looks like the numbers are not being an int, for some reason. >>   memory[index] += 1
>>TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str